# Grow left and right css animation

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to create a div that houses 2 buttons. One on the left and one on the right. When you hover into the box, I want both buttons to give the appearance of growing from their respective sides inwards in the div. I have coded what I want it to look like except when these buttons are outside of the div, I do not want the part that is outside the div to be visible. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```js
const $box = document.querySelector('.box');
const $leftButton = document.querySelector('.button-left');

const $rightButton = document.querySelector('.right');

$box.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
  $rightButton.classList.add('right-button-transform') 
  $leftButton.classList.add('left-button-transform');
  
})

$box.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
  $leftButton.classList.remove('left-button-transform');
  $rightButton.classList.remove('right-button-transform') 
})
```

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(201, 137, 211, 0.3);
    border-right: 1px solid rgba(186, 167, 252, 0.5);
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(186, 167, 252, 0.5);
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.button-left {
  display: grid;
  
  place-items: center;
  height: 50%;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  background: linear-gradient(
      90deg,
      rgba(201, 137, 211, 0.3) 0%,
      rgba(186, 167, 252, 0.5) 100%
    ) !important;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
  transform: translateX(-90%);
  transition: all 1s ease-in;
}

.left-button-transform {
  transform: translateX(0%)
}

.right-button-transform {
  transform: translateX(0%)
}

.right {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  height: 50%;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
   background: linear-gradient(
      90deg,
      rgba(201, 137, 211, 0.3) 0%,
      rgba(186, 167, 252, 0.5) 100%
    ) !important;
  border-top-left-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
  transform: translateX(90%);
  transition: all 1s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="button-left">+</div>
  <div class="right">x</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just a matter of [CSS precedence](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/css/precedence.html). Move your animation class to the bottom.

And for hiding the element, you can use `overflow: hidden;` on the parent, which is the `.box` element.

```js
const $box = document.querySelector('.box');
const $leftButton = document.querySelector('.button-left');

const $rightButton = document.querySelector('.right');

$box.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
  $rightButton.classList.add('right-button-transform')
  $leftButton.classList.add('left-button-transform');

})

$box.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
  $leftButton.classList.remove('left-button-transform');
  $rightButton.classList.remove('right-button-transform')
})
```

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(201, 137, 211, 0.3);
  border-right: 1px solid rgba(186, 167, 252, 0.5);
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(186, 167, 252, 0.5);
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden
}

.button-left {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  height: 50%;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  background: linear-gradient( 90deg, rgba(201, 137, 211, 0.3) 0%, rgba(186, 167, 252, 0.5) 100%) !important;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
  transform: translateX(-90%);
  transition: all 1s ease-in;
}

.right {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  height: 50%;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  background: linear-gradient( 90deg, rgba(201, 137, 211, 0.3) 0%, rgba(186, 167, 252, 0.5) 100%) !important;
  border-top-left-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
  transform: translateX(90%);
  transition: all 1s ease-in;
}

.left-button-transform {
  transform: translateX(0%)
}

.right-button-transform {
  transform: translateX(0%)
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="button-left">+</div>
  <div class="right">x</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to set `overflow: hidden;` on the parent div. See the snippet below:

```js
const $box = document.querySelector('.box');
const $leftButton = document.querySelector('.button-left');

const $rightButton = document.querySelector('.right');

$box.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
  $rightButton.classList.add('right-button-transform') 
  $leftButton.classList.add('left-button-transform');
  
})

$box.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
  $leftButton.classList.remove('left-button-transform');
  $rightButton.classList.remove('right-button-transform') 
})
```

```css
.box {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  border-left: 1px solid rgba(201, 137, 211, 0.3);
    border-right: 1px solid rgba(186, 167, 252, 0.5);
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(186, 167, 252, 0.5);
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.button-left {
  display: grid;
  
  place-items: center;
  height: 50%;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
  background: linear-gradient(
      90deg,
      rgba(201, 137, 211, 0.3) 0%,
      rgba(186, 167, 252, 0.5) 100%
    ) !important;
  border-top-right-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 15px;
  transform: translateX(-90%);
  transition: all 1s ease-in;
}

.left-button-transform {
  transform: translateX(0%)
}

.right-button-transform {
  transform: translateX(0%)
}

.right {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  height: 50%;
  padding-left: 30px;
  padding-right: 30px;
   background: linear-gradient(
      90deg,
      rgba(201, 137, 211, 0.3) 0%,
      rgba(186, 167, 252, 0.5) 100%
    ) !important;
  border-top-left-radius: 15px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 15px;
  transform: translateX(90%);
  transition: all 1s ease-in;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="button-left">+</div>
  <div class="right">x</div>
</div>
```